# Spring , Creation and lastUpdate return null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have some problems with the response that I get on PUT request. All changes are persisted and returns all data except these two fields: "created":"null","lastUpdated":"null". I don't understand why I get a Null here.

On POST however, everything works fine and as expected all data is contained within the response, including the two problematic fields: "created":"2014-10-28T19:55:37.889Z", "lastUpdated":"2014-10-28T19:55:37.889Z"

**My entity looks like this:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Project extends AbstractPersistable {

private String key;
private String name;
private String description;

@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime created;

@Column(name = "last_updated_date", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
private DateTime lastUpdated;

@PrePersist
public void onPersist() {
    this.created = new DateTime();
    this.lastUpdated = new DateTime();
}


@PreUpdate
public void onUpdate() {
    this.lastUpdated = new DateTime();
}

//Getter and setter methods
```

**This is my Resource class**

```
@Path("/")
@Component
public class ProjectsResource {

@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

@POST
@Path("projects")
@Consumes(CustomMediaTypes.SMARTGWT_JSON)
@Produces(CustomMediaTypes.SMARTGWT_JSON)
public Response create(Project project) throws ServiceException {
    projectService.createOrSave(project);
    ProjectModelsSerializer jsonSerializer = new ProjectModelsSerializer();
    jsonSerializer.visit(project);
    return     Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(jsonSerializer.asServiceResponse("success")).build();
}

@PUT
@Path("projects")
@Consumes(CustomMediaTypes.SMARTGWT_JSON)
@Produces(CustomMediaTypes.SMARTGWT_JSON)
public Object update(Project project) throws ServiceException {
    projectService.createOrSave(project);

    ProjectModelsSerializer jsonSerializer = new ProjectModelsSerializer();
    jsonSerializer.visit(project);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(jsonSerializer.asServiceResponse("success")).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your project instance used as a parameter is not managed by Persistence Context.

If you call javax.persistence.EntityManager#merge in your createOrSave method, the entity instance supplied as a parameter will not be managed. So you cannot see any change from database (like creation date or last update date).

However,  javax.persistence.EntityManager#merge creates and returns a new instance of your entity, copies this entity state, and makes this new instance managed, with creation date or last update date.

So, method projectService.createOrSave(project) should return a reference to the managed object:

```
Project createOrSave(Project project)
```

reference that you can pass to your json serializer.

javax.persistence.EntityManager#persist attachs the (new) instance you gave to the persistence context. For this reason, it works when you create a new project (with POST method)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have changed the @PUT with:
Project updated = projectService.createOrSave(project);
ProjectModelsSerializer jsonSerializer = new ProjectModelsSerializer();
jsonSerializer.visit(updated);
it only returns the "lastUpdated", "created" one is still null

Comment: Indeed if you use merge, creationDate is overwritten by the merge result, before the entity is returned to you (with hibernate implementation, you can have a look at `org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer#setPropertyValues`). What you can do is (in your createOrSave method): 1)merge your entity, 2)flush() persitence context to the database , 3) call refresh(entity) to retrieve creation date.

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228304/jpa-merge-readonly-fields . Another solution is to use a manual merge to set creationDate.

Comment: I can't flush or call refresh as I am using Spring repository. So in my createOrSave method I return projectRepository.save(project);